# Align widget to bottom of sibling column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I'm having trouble recreating the layout in the screenshot that follows two rules:

- The height of both `Column` is decided by the `Column` on the left, as the content (blue container) can be vary in different cases.
- The `Column` on the right should the same height than the column on the left and it's children (yellow and red containers) should be aligned to the top and bottom of the column accordingly.

[image]

This is what I currently have

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Container(
        color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.1),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 500,
                    width: 200,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 200,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 200,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Now onto the things I have tried and the problems:

1. Change right colum to `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,` results in the right column deciding the height.

[image]

2. Add `Spacer` in between the yellow and red container results in the right column expanding to the max height.

[image]

So the question is:
How can I constrain the height of the right column so

- follows the height of the left column without taking all the available height
- keeping the height of the entire layout dynamic (so no hardcoded heights for the blue container or left column)
- Aligns containers on the right column to the top and bottom of the the right column.

I have the feeling that I'm missing something or need a special widget that I'm not aware of. Maybe some advance usage of `Flexible`?

Any ideas or tips are more than welcome.
Thanks.

========================

Full solution based on [@Ivo Beckers answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71795788/961759)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Container(
        color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.1),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Center(
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 500,
                          width: 200,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: most likely you need [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Have you seen any good example using it? All the examples I can find always have children with defined height.

Comment: Is the width of the first column fixed?

Comment: @IvoBeckers for the sake of the example yes, it's fixed. But since this is mostly a vertical alignment problem, i don't believe that should be very relevant. Just curious, why are you asking?

Comment: I was thinking of using a Stack instead of a Row and then position the second column manually. But I'm not sure now if that could solve it

Comment: Use Column as parent instead of Container. This will give you more flexibility. Also, try using MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween in order to create space between the right column items.

Comment: @LeviRoelofsma you mean a Column as a parent of the Row ?

Comment: @RobertEstivill No, inside your row, you have Container widgets as children. Use Column instead with Container as child.

Comment: Added my final solution to the original question.

Comment: you dont need top `Container` + `Center` if you replace them with "standard" `Scaffold` widget - `home: Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.orange, body: IntrinsicHeight(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your example to work like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Container(
        color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.1),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Align(
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 500,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                        height: 100,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                        height: 100,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So basically the `Row` is wrapped in an `IntrinsicHeight` and that one in an `Align`. Just an `IntrinsicHeight` didn't seem to help. Furthermore a `Spacer()` between the `Container`s in the second `Column`

Comment: Yes, this seems to work.  However, it doesn't feel natural to use `Align`. I mean we are literally not aligning the row to anything, is almost like we are just wrapping it for the sake of wrapping it.  `Spacer()` or `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` do seem to both work to create the space between containers on the right column.

Comment: @RobertEstivill yeah, the `Align` seems a bit out of place. I don't know myself why including that one makes a difference, or if another kind of widget is maybe better

Comment: Funnily enough, using a `Column` instead of `Align` also seems to work ‍♂️

Comment: *"I don't know myself why including that one makes a difference, or if another kind of widget is maybe better"* - using `Align` without `alignment:` defaults to "center", this is a good source of knowledge: [Understanding constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: Based on your solution I was able to come up with mine. Marked as answered and also added my final solution to the original question. Thanks Ivo.

Comment: @pskink very useful link. Made me understand things better

Comment: yes indeed, especially those 29 examples provided are very useful by explaining how stuff internally works

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',

      home: Container(
        color: Colors.white,

        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
              color: Colors.green,
              child:  Container(
                height: 500,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),flex: 1,),
          const SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
          Flexible(child:   Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  height: 100,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  height: 50,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),flex: 1,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```